# How to pull sum of two columns along with the count of a relation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: buyers and orders. A buyer has many orders.

I want all the buyers along with the orders count and sum of two columns (price, charge) of orders for specific period of time. I can get the count by doing the following,

```
Buyer::withCount([
    'orders' => fn ($query) => $query
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo)
])
->get();
```

But how do I get the sum for specified period of time (`->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo)`)?

Comment: you can use whereDate() or where between

Comment: How to apply sum and whereDate on orders? @sandipbharadva

Comment: @miken32 it's not really a duplicate question since the answer you're referring to is an independent query which in this case will need a loop on every result to use it while this question ask for it to be eager loaded with the result via the method `withCount()` of Eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a variable inside a closure, you need to use `use()` to send its value to that function.

For the use of [`withSum({relation},{column})`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withSum) you need ro make a separate call for each.

```
Buyer::withCount([
        'orders' => function ($query) use ($dateTo) { 
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo);
        }
    ])
    ->withSum([
        'orders' => function ($query) use ($dateTo) { 
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo);
        }
    ], 'price')
    ->withSum([
        'orders' => function ($query) use ($dateTo) { 
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo);
        }
    ], 'charge')
    ->get();
```

`withSum()` is only available in Laravel version 8 or higher.

**Edit** for arrows function syntax

```
Buyer::withCount([
        'orders' => fn ($query) $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo),
    ])
    ->withSum(['orders' => fn ($query) $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo)], 'price')
    ->withSum(['orders' => fn ($query) $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo)], 'charge')
    ->get();
```

Comment: you cannot have a `use()` on php arrow function. You code won't compile.

Comment: @ml59 there, fixed it

Comment: Why not just leave the arrow functions in place, as in the question? Much neater.

Comment: @miken32 it is up to preference, and I'd rather use this format as it is more maintainable and uses less memory (that is why you dont need to use `use($dateTo)` for arrow functions)

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @miken32 you're right since php 7 unused variables event if available are not used in the compiled code so no memory usage difference. I still stand by the preference view point as I personally  find it more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you have [withSum()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions), here is how you can do it

```
Buyer::withCount([
            'orders' => fn($query) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo),
        ])->withSum([
            'orders' => fn($query) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo),
        ], 'price')->withSum([
            'orders' => fn($query) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', $dateTo),
        ], 'charge')->get();
```